# Exclude application.properties when generating war using spring boot and spring-boot-maven-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am developing a web application using Spring Boot, and want to generate war instead of jar.

It works very fine using the conversion from jar to war described here : http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

But I want to exclude the application.properties from the war, because I use `@PropertySource(value = "file:${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/application.properties")` to get the file path on production environment.

- This method works when generating my war, but in eclipse I can't run my application because application.properties not copied at all to target/classes :

  ```
  <build>
      <resources> 
          <resource> 
              <directory>src/main/resources</directory> 
              <excludes> 
                  <exclude>application.properties</exclude> 
              </excludes> 
          </resource> 
       </resources> 
  </build>
  ```
- This method doesn't work at all, I think that spring-boot-maven-plugin doesn't support packagingExcludes :

  ```
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration> 
                  <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/application.properties</packagingExcludes> 
              </configuration> 
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
  ```

Have you another suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: My approach to this problem is to just override the packaged configuration using `spring.config.location` parameter. I set it in Tomcat's context file for example to point to the configuration file I use in production environment. Have you tried doing it like this or is this solution not ideal for you?

Or you could perhaps achieve exactly what you are trying to do by using different Maven build profiles for dev and production? I mean that application.properties would be excluded only if you packaged your app with production Maven profile ...

Comment: I want only exclude application.properties when I package my war using maven, everything else works fine. I don't want to delete application.properties after generating the war.

Answer (score 15):

Try using the solution below. This will work:

```
<build>
    <resources>
         <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If you are using the above solution , while running the project in Eclipse IDE you may get error that the properties file is not found. To get rid of this you need to add the resources folder in Run as configuration.(Run configurations... -> Classpath -> User Entries -> Advanced... -> Add Folders)

Comment: This prevents the application.properties from being filtered which the most developers want and is also messing up with the Spring Boot default resource setting and filtering. A better solution is the modify the war plugin and exclude any properties file. The tried `<packagingExcludes>...</packagingExcludes>` must be used with the `maven-war-plugin` not the spring-boot-maven-plugin plugin.

Answer (score 4):

When running in Eclipse, at your Run Configuration, you need to specify the path of the propeties to Spring Boot:

```
--spring.config.location=${workspace_loc:/YOURPROYECTNAME}/src/main/resources/
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I added is to unzip my packaged war, delete the file application.properties and create a new war named ROOT.war using maven-antrun-plugin and run some ant tasks.

this is what i added to my plugins in pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>package</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
            <target>
                <unzip src="target/${artifactId}-${version}.${packaging}" dest="target/ROOT/" />
                <delete file="target/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties"/>
                <zip destfile="target/ROOT.war" basedir="target/ROOT" encoding="UTF-8"/>
                <delete dir="target/ROOT"/>
            </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

I named my target war as ROOT.war because I am using tomcat on openshift PaaS, so I just copy my ROOT.war and push to my openshift repo. That's it

Comment: IMHO the right answer. I needed it with a slight twist: I want to include `application.properties` but none of my profile `application-*.properties`. And because my ANT days have long gone, it took me a while to figure out the right syntax thus posting it here:
`<delete dir="target/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/" includes="application-*.properties" />`

Comment: This worked for me. I created two separate profiles each containing their own build, one build deletes the file the other build keeps the file

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from your question is, you want to use application.properties for your development. But you dont want to use it for production.

I would suggest using **Spring profiles** to achieve this.
In your properties file

1. Create a profile for development. Put all your development properties under it.
2. Do not create a profile for production in your properties file.
3. When you are developing, set active profile to development, so that the properties are loaded from your **application.properties** file.
4. When you run it in production, set active profile to Production. Though application.properties will be loaded into your WAR, since there is no profile for production, none of the properties will be loaded.

I have done something similar using YML. I am sure there must be a way to do the same thing using `.properties` file too.

```
spring:
  profiles.active: development
--
spring:
  profiles: development
something:
  location: USA
  unit1: Test1
  unit2: Test2
```

You could change the profile in run time using

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=production
```

Comment: yes and no. If you store those profile-properties files in src/main/resources,  you can't load them from a parent classloadeder (like putting them in $TCHOME/lib) as they are already bundled in the WAR itself

Answer (score 0):

Try to using this solution:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <addResources>false</addResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**<addResources>false</addResources>** will keep properties when you run mvn spring-boot:run